# Trezor - How to see the balance on a particular address?

Tags: public-key, hd-wallets, trezor

Trezor uses MEW or MyCrypto to display the balance of my Ethereum accounts. 
However, I cannot enter a particular address and have the website search for that wallet in my HD derivation path. 
I know that it is not a problem with a solution in general (since the user could enter a wallet that do not belong to the Trezor and the program would never know if it did not find yet or if does not exists), but if I could generate a hundreds of address and check, it would be better than the option at the moment.

How can I search for a particular address (even if for a limited number) in Trezor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gist that I created searches for the addresses in Trezor in order using teh same derivation Path that MEW and MyCrypto does.

The key thing was finding the correct commands in the Trezor CL tool that returns an address. From that the Python script loops over calling the same command with different parameters to get the keys.

To see the balance one could query a node in each pass.

https://gist.github.com/mauhcs/d07f3e71626e646f1609f471b0fb5fdd